# "FileNotFoundError" in python after freezing the app

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, pathlib, os.path

As a part of a python application, files in unmapped network drive are accessed. The script runs like a charm when running the .py file, but after freezing it as an .exe file using cx_freeze I am getting the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\foo\bar\baz\file.txt'`

When running the following line:

`sizelist = [float(Path(x).stat().st_size) for x in ListOfFiles]`

The file definitely exists. I have noticed that under file properties in Windows, the file path is shown as:

`\\?\UNC\foo\bar\baz\file.txt`

What is the reason for this error and how would you fix it?

I have tried working with pathlib and os, and upgrading to python 3.11 (latest available version).

**EDIT:** I have isolated the issue as caused by cx_Freeze. I have frozen the following script in cx_Freeze and pyinstaller:

```py
# encoding: utf-8

from pathlib import Path

folder = input("Folder:")
file_list = []
file_list += list(Path(folder).rglob("**/*.mdf"))
file_list += list(Path(folder).rglob("**/*.mf4"))
file_list += list(Path(folder).rglob("**/*.dat"))
print([(Path(p), Path(p).is_file()) for p in file_list]) # For tracking

x = input("Press enter...")
```

When frozen with pyinstaller, Path(p).is_file() is True for all files. With cx_Freeze, the behavious is the same as previously described.

Is it there a way to solve this issue on cx_Freeze?

Comment: Try using absolute paths

Comment: Are you mapping the directory and using the paths found, or are you using this as a hard coded path? Things get moved around when you create an executable, so its never a good idea to hard code a relative file path (or an absolute path if you intend for this to be used on different machines).

Comment: I am using absolute paths. I obtain the paths by mapping the directory using 'Path(folder).rglob("**/*")'